# How to move a substring with preg_replace or preg_match in PHP?

Tags: preg-replace, preg-match

I want to find a substring and move it in the string instead of replacing (for example, moving it from the beginning to the end of the string).

```
'THIS the rest of the string' -> 'the rest of the string THIS'
```

I do this by the following code

```
preg_match('/^(THIS).?/', $str, $match);
$str = trim( $str . $match[1] );
$str = preg_replace('/^(THIS).?/', '', $str);
```

There should be an easier way to do this with one regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
$re = '/^(THIS)\b\s*(.*)/s';
$str = 'THIS the rest of the string';
$result = preg_replace($re, '$2 $1', $str);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7VxAVp/1) and a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/H8OBvd).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(THIS)` - Group 1 (referenced to with `$1` from the replacement pattern): `THIS`
- `\b` - a word boundary (if you do not need a whole word, you may remove it)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces (if there is always at least one whitespace, use `\s+` and remove `\b`, as it will become redundant)
- `(.*)` - Group 2 (referenced to with `$2` from the replacement pattern): the rest of the string (`s` modifier allows `.` match line break chars, too).

Comment: Worked like a charm. Just a follow-up question. Is there a way to apply PHP functions to `$1`? For example, `lcfirst($1)`?

Comment: @Googlebot Not exactly, use `preg_replace_callback`.